# Exclude a service from a plugin at Kong configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kong-plugin

I have 40 services at my Kong configuration and have a global auth plugin in place, I want to exclude few services from auth for which I don't find a way to exclude few service from plugin, any help? I don't really know if there is a way to exclude a service from Kong plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to exclude services from existing plugins at the route (e.g. ingress) level. what you could try is removing the ingress plugin and replace it with the same plugin for each individual service that you want it to apply to, and simply not do this for the 6 or so services that you want to be exempt. applying a plugin for a service works in the same way that it does for an ingress, i.e. the kong plugin annotation in the manifest's metadata (assuming you are using K8s)